# JpaRepository Querydsl : Qclass not generates

Tags: maven, spring-boot, querydsl

I find that there is many question like mine but  never had the answer to enable **Querydsl** in my **Spring-boot** project.
this is my `pom.xml` dependency and plugin:

```
    <properties>
        <querydsl.version>3.7.4</querydsl.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            //added for QueryDsl
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-apt-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

and this is my Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "phone_table")
public class Phone {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long phoneId;
private String phoneName;
private String phoneBrand;
private String phoneManufacturer;
...
```

and this is the repository:

```
@Repository
public interface MobileRepository extends JpaRepository<Phone,Long> ,QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Phone>{

}
```

my project do not run and it is error says  `Did not find a query class ir.mtajik.entities.QPhone for domain class ir.mtajik.entities.Phone` and cause by :can not create QPhone class. I googled so much. there are lots of question like mine but answers are not working in my situation.
I tried these:

1. chose dependency and plugin from same version
2. Try to use `@Document` but it not working and do not know where to put that.
3. I tried many version of **querydsl** but the error is same

Comment: QueryDSL and Spring Boot's versions might be causing this issue. 

try spring boot 1.4.4 and 3.7.4 for query dsl and its dependents.

Comment: @MuhammadFaisalHyder Unfortunately no. it is not works

Answer (score 7):

It worked for me when I changed the processor.

So you have it as:

```
<configuration>
        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
        <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
</configuration>
```

Change it to :

```
<configuration>
         <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
         <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
</configuration>
```

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 6):

as mentioned in comments along with that you also need to configure Maven-apt plugin for Query DSL, so add this in pom Plugins section:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.1.3</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>process</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
            <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Hope this helps. [This Spring Article](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/) will help you. And Don't forget to **mvn clean install**

Also make sure, Beans are defined either XML based or Java Based for EntityManager, Jpa Vendor, and  pointing to your Repo package.

Comment: are you sure abdout apt-maven-plugin not maven-apt-plugin? what do you mean about mvn clean install?

Comment: mvn clean install to generate Q(Entity class/es) it is Maven command.
maven-apt-plugin

Comment: ok I put you code instead of my plugin. they were very same. then clean and install the maven. but error is still remain.

Comment: clean build your project..., Post complete pom.xml and stack trace please.

Comment: I need more space for posting all code. can you start chat here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135794/discussion-between-kenji-and-muhammad-faisal-hyder).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this dependencies. It works fine for me.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
  <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
  <version>3.7.4</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
  <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
  <version>3.7.4</version>
 </dependency>

<plugin>
  <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.3</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>process</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
        <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```